# How to get data from mysql to the select option in php

Tags: php

I have 2 tables: Students and Classes. In table Classes, I have a column "name" and in table Students I have a column "class" with input as select option. I want to get data from "name" to the select option. Anyone can help me?
This is my source code:

```
<?php 
    include "connect.php";
    if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
        $id = $_GET['id'];
            $sqlClass = "select * from classes where id = $id";
            $result = $conn->query($sqlClass);
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                $classes[] = $result->fetch_assoc();

            } else{
                die('class not found'); 
            }   
    }

    $sql = "select count(name) from classes";
    $total = $conn->query($sql);
    $totalClass = $total->fetch_assoc()['count(name)'];


?>

<div class="form-group">
                        <label for="">Class</label>
                        <select name="" id="input" class="form-control" required="required">
                            <?php 
                                for ($i=1; $i <= $totalClass ; $i++) { 
                             ?>
                             <option value="<?=$i?>"><?php echo $classes['name']; ?></option>
                            <?php } ?>

                        </select>
                    </div>
```

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Answer (score 0):

Your `select` needs a name (if you don't name it you will never find it when you post the data) and you don't need the second query to get a count, just an iterator for each option:

```
<?php 
    include "connect.php";
    if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $sqlClass = "select * from classes where id = $id";
        $result = $conn->query($sqlClass);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            $classes[] = $result->fetch_assoc();

        } else{
            die('class not found'); 
        }   
    }

?>

<div class="form-group">
     <label for="">Class</label>
     <select name="A_NAME_IS_REQUIRED" id="input" class="form-control" required="required">
      <?php
          $i = 1;
          foreach($classes AS $class) { 
      ?>
              <option value="<?=$i?>"><?php echo $class['name']; ?</option>
      <?php
          $i++; 
      } 
      ?>
      </select>
</div>
```

In addition, you will want to check if `$classes` is an array. If it isn't there would be no sense in creating the drop-down.

**SQL Injection Warning!**

[Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!